# React onClick `this` binding

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
export default React.createClass({

displayName: 'Test',

  onItemClick(item) {
    console.log(item);
  },

render() {
  return <div onClick={() => this.onItemClick('apple')}>Fruit</div>
});
```

When clicking the div I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onItemClick' of undefined`. Tried also using `bind`, but with same result.

**Later edit:**

The actual code is different. I'm populating the `items` arrays inside the `circle` object with `div` objects. Outside the loop, if I call the `onItemClick()` function it works fine, but inside the loop I get the error above.

```
export default React.createClass({

displayName: 'Test',

onItemClick (item) {
    console.log(item);
  },

render() {
    var circle = { 
        'one':   { items: [] }, 
        'two':   { items: [] }, 
        'three': { items: [] }, 
        'four':  { items: [] } 
    };

    ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'].forEach(function (k, i) {
      for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        var itemNo = (i * 10 + j);
        circle[k].items.push(<div className={"item item-"+itemNo} onClick={() => this.onItemClick(itemNo)}>{itemNo}</div>);
      }
    });
return (
    <div>{circle.one.items}</div>
)};
```

How can I address this problem?

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation. Maybe this is a webpack problem?

Comment: I don't think it's a webpack problem, although it might be worthwhile to see if the transpiler code for your component makes sense. What are you using to transpile it?

Comment: Agreed, binding is not necessary if your are using `React.createClass`.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. The problem was the scope of `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `forEach` handler is a standard function and has a different `this`. Replace it by an arrow function and you should be fine.

```
render() {
  var circle = { 
    'one':   { items: [] }, 
    'two':   { items: [] }, 
    'three': { items: [] }, 
    'four':  { items: [] } 
  };
  ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'].forEach((k, i) => {
//                                         ^^^^^^^^^^
    for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
      var itemNo = (i * 10 + j);
      circle[k].items.push(<div className={"item item-"+itemNo} onClick={() => this.onItemClick(itemNo)}>{itemNo}</div>);
    }
  });
  return (
    <div>{circle.one.items}</div>
  )};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return <div onClick={this.onItemClick.bind(this, 'apple')}>Fruit</div>
```

Bind `onItemClick` to the component and fill the first argument with `'apple'`

Comment: This should do it I think. If you already have the function declared you don't need to use the arrow function imo. Cleaner, more efficient. If I'm not mistaken, `bind(this)` won't work with the arrow function anyway.

Comment: I've tried both ways, using arrow function and bind. I'm working on an already built-up functional app, and I've passed data to functions this way in my previous components. This problem is insane! Is it maybe a webpack problem?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. The problem was the scope of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `forEach` handler, `this` loses its scope.

```
let _this = this;
```

So I've declared `_this` above the loop and used it inside.

```
render() {
  var circle = { 
    'one':   { items: [] }, 
    'two':   { items: [] }, 
    'three': { items: [] }, 
    'four':  { items: [] } 
  };
  var _this = this;
  ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'].forEach(function (k, i) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
      var itemNo = (i * 10 + j);
      circle[k].items.push(<div className={"item item-"+itemNo} onClick={() => _this.onItemClick(itemNo)}>{itemNo}</div>);
  }
                                          });
  return (
    <div>{circle.one.items}</div>
  )
}
```